# Google chart enabled page not loading when uploaded to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I uploaded the following index.html file for a subdomain and it isn't properly loading. It only shows the title tag.

I want it to load when I go to xxx.myapp.com. The setup is ok on godaddy because I see the title, but the rest of the page doesn't render. Also I see the network requests on the server bit nothing...

Any thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MI Testing title</title>

    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myapp.com/JS/HelperFunctions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myapp.com/JS/Settings.js"></script>

    <!-- zurb foundation-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.myapp.com/foundation-4.3.1/CSS/foundation.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.myapp.com/foundation-4.3.1/CSS/foundation.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.myapp.com/foundation-4.3.1/CSS/normalize.css" />

    <!--Local css -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.myapp.com/CSS/AnalyticsIndex.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);

        /*
        Called when library loaded
         */
        function drawCharts(){
            drawDailyAverageSessionLength();
            drawUsersGender();
        }

        /*
        Draws the chart for average session length by day
         */
        function drawDailyAverageSessionLength() {

            //Apit to get the data from
            var api = GET_AVG_SESSIONS_URL+"2013/0/0";

            //Request data (using jquery/ajax)
            $.getJSON(api,function(data){

                //Start a days and seconds array
                var days = [];
                var seconds = [];

                //Init google data array
                var googData = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                //Add X Y columns
                googData.addColumn('string', 'days');
                googData.addColumn('number', 'seconds');

                //Init sort array
                var sorted =[];

                //Parse the results to get the dates
                for (var key in data){
                    var date = new Date(key);
                    sorted.push(date);
                }

                //Sort the array
                sorted.sort(sortDateArrayDescending);

                //Split results
                for (i=0;i<sorted.length;i++){

                    //Get the date object
                    var day = sorted[i];

                    //Add 1 to month
                    var month = day.getMonth()+1;

                    //Parse to string
                    var newKey = day.getFullYear()+'-'+month+'-'+day.getDate();

                    var short = month+'/'+day.getDate();

                   //Add date to days array
                    days.push(short);

                    //Add to integer array
                    seconds.push(parseInt(data[newKey]));
                 }

                //Parse to google data
                for (i=0; i<days.length;i++){
                    googData.addRow([days[i], seconds[i]]);
                }

                // Set chart options
                var options = {'title':'Average session length (NOT ACCURATE since end of sessions aren\'t being tracked)',
                    'width':1200,
                    'height':400};

                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('averageSessionLengthChart'));
                chart.draw(googData, options);
            });
        }

        /*
         Draws the chart for average session length by day
         */
        function drawUsersGender() {

            //Apit to get the data from
            var api = GET_USERS_SEX;

            //Request data (using jquery/ajax)
            $.getJSON(api,function(data){

                //Start a days and seconds array
                var result = [['gender', 'number']];

                //Iterate over the genders
                for (var gender in data){

                    //Get the value pair and push
                    var entry = [gender, parseInt(data[gender])];
                    result.push(entry);
                }

                //Parse to google data
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);

                //Display options
                var options = {
                    title:'Gender for registered users',
                    'width':600,
                    'height':400
                };

                //Draw the chart
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('genderChart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            });
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">

        <div id = "averageSessionLengthChart" class="large-12 small-12 columns">
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div id = "genderChart" class="large-12 small-12 columns">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you store your data ? I don't get the 
`var api = GET_AVG_SESSIONS_URL+"2013/0/0";`

Comment: Its another settings.js file

Comment: I am getting the GET requests canceled by JQuery, it may be my headers on the reply (from my java server)

Comment: Do you have a link to show your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a developper console from a PC outside your network to see what requests are sent (Press 'F12' on chrome or install the firebug extension on Firefox). 
There should be a "Network" tab that shows what requests are made from the page. 
Maybe it will help you understand what is happening.